# Declaring a NancyModule with generics

Tags: c#, generics, nancy

Is it possible to create nancy module like so:

```
public class TypeParamModule<Type1, Type2, Type3> : NancyModule
{
    public TypeParamModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters =>
        {
            //action here
        }
    }
}
```

If it's possible, where do I set the type params. Do I "hard" register the module somewhere in the bootstrapper?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want a generic module? Are you trying to do some sort of scaffolding?

Comment: The module has a few dependencies that have type parameters and I want to be able to reuse this module across multiple projects. Am I missing a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must declare `TypeParamModule` as `abstract` to avoid Nancy auto try create instance for it
Then, you can create any specify module as: `PersonModule: TypeParamModule<Person, City, Nation>`